# Symfony2 Save Form Data via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a form in Symfony that needed to be submitted via ajax call. I worte the code but it's not saving any data in db but also doesn't give/show any error.

```
send_dict = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    processData: true,
    data: $('#Form').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(request) {alert('before send');},
    success: function (data) {alert("success")},
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
        alert('Some Thing Went Wrong, Please Refresh and Try Again...');
    }
}
$.ajax(send_dict);


public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $address = new Addresses();

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // Do something...
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $request = $this->get('request');
            $permanent_is_present   = $request->get('permanent_is_present');
            $present_address  = $request->get('present_address');
            $present_address_country   = $request->get('present_address_country');
            // Persisting Objects to the Database
            if($permanent_is_present==true){
                $address->isIsPresent(true);
                $address->isIsPermanent(true);
            }else{
                $address->isIsPresent(true);
            }
            $address->setUser($user);

            $address->setStreet1($present_address);
            $address->setCountry($present_address_country);
            $address->setState($present_address_state);
            $address->setCity($present_address_city);
            //exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($address));
            // Entity Manager To Get Connected with Doctrine
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            // Persists the entire objects....
            $em->persist($address);
            // Flush queries into database
            $em->flush();
            $output = array();
            $response = new Response();
            $output[] = array('success' => true);
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            $response->setContent(json_encode($output));
            return $response;
        }else{
            return $this->render('AddressBundle:Addresses:new.html.twig');
        }
    } else {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('address_new'));
    }

}
```

both alerts in before send and success on ajax function are showing. but the data is not saved in the database? New to symfony, also don't know how to trace/debug this?

**UPDATE:**
One more thing i notice that there is no user login in the system, and em trying to made ajax calls. and it is sending to controller and because user id is not found so it is not saving into database

Comment: probably a scoping issue with `$(this).attr('action')` - what do you expect `this` to refer to?

Comment: create a form object controller side, then bind the request.  Then you can validate properly.  [heres](http://codemonkeys.be/2013/01/ajaxify-your-symfony2-forms-with-jquery/) a reasonable resource to help you.

Comment: @Steve `action="{{path('address_create')}}"`

Comment: @DevDonkey i have done so many form using symfony form builer, but this for has to done this way.

Comment: @MTaqi Sure, but the point is `this` wont refer to the form that attribute is on, because its called in a global function. `this` will likely refer to the window object, which wont have an action attribute

Comment: @Steve see the updated question, how can i secure this controller so that only if user is login then ajax request is made or only execute result if use is login else return error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize form data. Give your form an Id attribute then:

```
data: $('#Form').serialize(),
```